# Prove $\int_{R^1}{\frac{\delta^{\lambda}(y)f(y)}{|x-y|^{1+\lambda}}\,dy}$ is integrable and finite almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fubini-tonelli-theorems

> Let $F$ be a closed subset of $R^1$ and let $δ(x) = δ(x, F)$ be the corresponding
> distance function. If $λ > 0$ and $f$ is nonnegative and integrable over the
> complement of $F$, prove that the function
> $\int_{R^1}{\frac{\delta^{\lambda}(y)f(y)}{|x-y|^{1+\lambda}}\,dy}$ is integrable over $F$ and so is finite a.e. in $F$.

I'm stuck with this problem from my analysis textbook. Could anyone point me in the right direction or provide a solution? I know in the case of $f = χ_{(a,b)}$ this reduces to Marcinkiewicz theorem, but I cannot finish the problem with just that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A general $L^1$ function can be approximated by characteristic functions.